# Generating URL's for Pie Chart's Section Label using JFree Chart API

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart, pie-chart

How to generate URL's for labels for Pie Charts using JFree Chart package.We can extend the PieSectionLabelGenerator but i would need examples to show how.
Please advice!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is it correct that you want to click on the URL in the label in order to open the URL in a browser?

Comment: And to further clarify is your chart on a web page or in swing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static class CustomLegendGenerator
        implements PieSectionLabelGenerator {

    public String generateSectionLabel(final PieDataset dataset, final Comparable key) {
        String temp = null;
        if (dataset != null) {
            temp = key.toString();
            if (key.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("abc")) {
                temp = temp + " (abc String)";
            }
            if (key.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("xyz")) {
                temp = temp + " (xyz description)";
            }
            if (key.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("klm")) {
                temp = temp + " (Klm description)";
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public AttributedString generateAttributedSectionLabel(PieDataset pd, Comparable cmprbl) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke `setLabelGenerator()` on your `PiePlot`. The `MessageFormat` *ArgumentIndex* values correspond to the **series name**, **value** and **percentage**. You can reference them in your label generator, as shown below:

```
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} {1} {2}"));
```

Addendum:

> I am looking for a URL/Hyperlink.

Add a `ChartMouseListener` to your `ChartPanel`; you can obtain the link from the `ChartEntity` of the corresponding `ChartMouseEvent`. You can use `java.awt.Desktop` to open the URL in a browser.

Comment: I would imagine that would give me a String Label. I am looking for a URL/Hyperlink.

Comment: @gpmattoo: Just set the URL to the same value as the label.

Comment: If you can share the code snippet of the ChartMouseListener thing you said above, that would help. Note that I am using JDK 1.4.

Comment: @gpmattoo: There's a `ChartMouseListener` example here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309045. It looks like `java.awt.Desktop` requires Java SE 6.

Answer (score 0):

*Note this answer is targeted for those making urls and maps for charts used in web pages*

**For Making the Pie Segments Themselves URLs by using an HTML Map:**
I would advise that you actually extend the `StandardPieURLGenerator`. Then you only need to do two things:

*Add The Data*

Either through constructor arguments or setters, make a way to add the data into fields within your class.

*Override generateURL*

generateURL will be called when the JFreeChart is wanting the generator to make a URL. If you are wanting to add parameters then I would do something like this:

```
public String generateURL(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key, int pieIndex)
{
  return super.generateURL(dataset, key, pieIndex) + "&amp;" + yourParameters;
}
```

---

**To Add URLs in the Label**

Extend the `StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator` and override `generateAttributedSectionLabel` instead for the same steps above. Your function will now look more like this:

```
public String generateAttributedSectionLabel(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key)
{
  return super.generateAttributedSectionLabel(dataset, key) + "&lt;a href=&quot;YOUR_URL_HERE&quot; /&gt;";
}
```

Comment: I would imagine that would be for URL generator for PIE Charts. However, what i am looking for is URL for Pie Labels i.e. custom class implementing PieSectionLabelGenerator interface http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/PieSectionLabelGenerator.html or something of that sort.

Comment: @gpmatto Ahh sorry, misread. Let me just write up a new answer for that one.