# Get value when a point on line chart is clicked

Tags: java, mouseevent, jfreechart

I have a time JFreeChart which displays the temperature of the last 30 days. Now I want when I click on a random point on the chart, it should give me the temperature value of this point.

Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT**:

Here is the code I used:

```
package org.skzr.chart4me.demo.time;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.*;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class TimeSeriesDemo1 extends ApplicationFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TimeSeriesDemo1(String s) {
        super(s);
        JPanel jpanel = createDemoPanel();
        jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(jpanel);
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset xydataset) {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                "Legal & General Unit Trust Prices", "Date", "Price Per Unit",
                xydataset, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        xyplot.setDomainPannable(true);
        xyplot.setRangePannable(false);
        xyplot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        xyplot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
        org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer xyitemrenderer = xyplot
                .getRenderer();
        if (xyitemrenderer instanceof XYLineAndShapeRenderer) {
            XYLineAndShapeRenderer xylineandshaperenderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) xyitemrenderer;
            xylineandshaperenderer.setBaseShapesVisible(false);
        }
        DateAxis dateaxis = (DateAxis) xyplot.getDomainAxis();
        dateaxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy"));
        return jfreechart;
    }

    private static XYDataset createDataset() {
        TimeSeries timeseries = new TimeSeries("L&G European Index Trust");
        timeseries.add(new Month(2, 2001), 181.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(3, 2001), 167.30000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(4, 2001), 153.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(5, 2001), 167.59999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(6, 2001), 158.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(7, 2001), 148.30000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(8, 2001), 153.90000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(9, 2001), 142.69999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(10, 2001), 123.2D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(11, 2001), 131.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(12, 2001), 139.59999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(1, 2002), 142.90000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(2, 2002), 138.69999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(3, 2002), 137.30000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(4, 2002), 143.90000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(5, 2002), 139.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(6, 2002), 137D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(7, 2002), 132.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(8, 2002), 110.3D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(9, 2002), 110.5D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(10, 2002), 94.109999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(11, 2002), 102.5D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(12, 2002), 112.3D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(1, 2003), 104D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(2, 2003), 98.530000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(3, 2003), 97.150000000000006D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(4, 2003), 94.900000000000006D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(5, 2003), 107.8D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(6, 2003), 113.7D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(7, 2003), 112.5D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(8, 2003), 118.59999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(9, 2003), 123.8D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(10, 2003), 117.2D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(11, 2003), 123D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(12, 2003), 127D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(1, 2004), 132.69999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(2, 2004), 132.40000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(3, 2004), 131.69999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(4, 2004), 128D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(5, 2004), 131.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(6, 2004), 127.40000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(7, 2004), 133.5D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(8, 2004), 126D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(9, 2004), 129.5D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(10, 2004), 135.30000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(11, 2004), 138D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(12, 2004), 141.30000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(1, 2005), 148.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(2, 2005), 147.09999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(3, 2005), 150.69999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(4, 2005), 150D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(5, 2005), 145.69999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(6, 2005), 152D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(7, 2005), 157.19999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(8, 2005), 167D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(9, 2005), 165D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(10, 2005), 171.59999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(11, 2005), 166.19999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(12, 2005), 174.30000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(1, 2006), 183.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(2, 2006), 187D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(3, 2006), 191.30000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(4, 2006), 202.5D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(5, 2006), 200.59999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(6, 2006), 187.30000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(7, 2006), 192.19999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(8, 2006), 190.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(9, 2006), 194.69999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(10, 2006), 201.30000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(11, 2006), 205.09999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(12, 2006), 206.69999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(1, 2007), 216.80000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(2, 2007), 218D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(3, 2007), 215.40000000000001D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(4, 2007), 223D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(5, 2007), 235.09999999999999D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(6, 2007), 242D);
        timeseries.add(new Month(7, 2007), 237.80000000000001D);
        TimeSeries timeseries1 = new TimeSeries("L&G UK Index Trust");
        timeseries1.add(new Month(2, 2001), 129.59999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(3, 2001), 123.2D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(4, 2001), 117.2D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(5, 2001), 124.09999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(6, 2001), 122.59999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(7, 2001), 119.2D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(8, 2001), 116.5D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(9, 2001), 112.7D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(10, 2001), 101.5D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(11, 2001), 106.09999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(12, 2001), 110.3D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(1, 2002), 111.7D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(2, 2002), 111D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(3, 2002), 109.59999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(4, 2002), 113.2D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(5, 2002), 111.59999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(6, 2002), 108.8D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(7, 2002), 101.59999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(8, 2002), 90.950000000000003D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(9, 2002), 91.019999999999996D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(10, 2002), 82.370000000000005D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(11, 2002), 86.319999999999993D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(12, 2002), 91D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(1, 2003), 86D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(2, 2003), 80.040000000000006D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(3, 2003), 80.400000000000006D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(4, 2003), 80.280000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(5, 2003), 86.420000000000002D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(6, 2003), 91.400000000000006D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(7, 2003), 90.519999999999996D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(8, 2003), 93.109999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(9, 2003), 96.799999999999997D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(10, 2003), 94.780000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(11, 2003), 99.560000000000002D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(12, 2003), 100.8D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(1, 2004), 103.40000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(2, 2004), 102.09999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(3, 2004), 105.3D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(4, 2004), 103.7D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(5, 2004), 105.2D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(6, 2004), 103.7D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(7, 2004), 105.7D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(8, 2004), 103.59999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(9, 2004), 106.09999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(10, 2004), 109.3D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(11, 2004), 110.3D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(12, 2004), 112.59999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(1, 2005), 116D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(2, 2005), 117.3D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(3, 2005), 120.09999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(4, 2005), 119.3D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(5, 2005), 116.2D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(6, 2005), 120.8D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(7, 2005), 125.2D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(8, 2005), 127.7D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(9, 2005), 130.80000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(10, 2005), 131D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(11, 2005), 135.30000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(12, 2005), 141.19999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(1, 2006), 144.69999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(2, 2006), 146.40000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(3, 2006), 151.90000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(4, 2006), 153.5D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(5, 2006), 144.5D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(6, 2006), 150.09999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(7, 2006), 148.69999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(8, 2006), 150.09999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(9, 2006), 151.59999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(10, 2006), 153.40000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(11, 2006), 158.30000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(12, 2006), 157.59999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(1, 2007), 163.90000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(2, 2007), 163.80000000000001D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(3, 2007), 162D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(4, 2007), 167.09999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(5, 2007), 170D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(6, 2007), 175.69999999999999D);
        timeseries1.add(new Month(7, 2007), 171.90000000000001D);
        TimeSeriesCollection timeseriescollection = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        timeseriescollection.addSeries(timeseries);
        timeseriescollection.addSeries(timeseries1);
        return timeseriescollection;
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TimeSeriesDemo1 timeseriesdemo1 = new TimeSeriesDemo1(
                "Time Series Demo 1");
        timeseriesdemo1.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(timeseriesdemo1);
        timeseriesdemo1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

([link to code](http://chart4me.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/chart4me/demo/org/skzr/chart4me/demo/time/TimeSeriesDemo1.java))

Comment: If you need interactive charts, JFreeChart can't do the job IMHO. Check out javascript chart solutions like Google Charts/Visualizations - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: i used the demo timeseries1demo code.. check my edit

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308939/jfreechart-obtain-data-source-value-on-mouse-click) for a solution

Comment: Try a `ChartMouseListener`, as shown in [JFreeChart simple plot (parabola)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081801/jfreechart-simple-plot-parabola)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This other question showed me how to do it: [JFreeChart : obtain data source value on mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308939/jfreechart-obtain-data-source-value-on-mouse-click)

Here's my final code:

```
panel_Letzte24H.addChartMouseListener((new ChartMouseListener() {
    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent mE) {
        System.out.println(mE.getEntity());
        String full = mE.getEntity().toString();
        String[] firstSplit = full.split("item = ");
        String[] finalSplit= firstSplit[1].split(",");
        try{
            int index;
            index = Integer.parseInt(finalSplit[0]);
            System.out.println("Indexnumber: " + index);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){}
    }

    public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {
        // nothing here
    }
}));
```

I had to split the string twice to get the index number.

Comment: Please post the solution in the answer section for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in two steps.  First, find the x-value on the axis that corresponds to the point where the mouse is clicked. trashgod gives some good hints on this in the comments above.

Once you know the x-value, you can use [DatasetUtilities.findYValue(...)](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/DatasetUtilities.html#findYValue%28org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset,%20int,%20double%29) to find the corresponding y-value (interpolated if necessary).